# Typename and variable in templates

Tags: c++, templates

I want to do structure with some type and with ability to use another comparator somewhen.This way of do template is not work.How I can do it correct?

```
template<typename T, typename Comparator = std::less<T>>
struct list_heap{};
bool min(int &a, int &b){return a<b;};
int main(){list_heap<int>r;list_heap<int, min>rr;return 0;};
```

Comment: And *how* does it not work? If you get compiler error, please copy and paste it into the question.

Comment: Compiler says that min must be typename. It is logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min` is a name of a function, not a type. The type of `min` is `bool(*)(int&, int&)`.

You can initialize your struct by giving the full type name:

```
list_heap<int, bool(*)(int&, int&)> rr;
//or something that bool(*)(int&, int&) will be convertible to:
list_heap<int, std::function<bool(int&, int&)>> rr;
```

Or by utilizing `decltype` to let compiler deduce the type:

```
list_heap<int, decltype(min)> rr;
```

---

If you cannot edit `main`, the only other option is to change `min` into function object:

```
struct min
{
    bool operator()(int &a, int &b){return a<b;};
};
```

---

Make sure you don't have `using namespace std;` in your code or `std::min` might collide with your own `min`.

Comment: But I need change template, not main.

Comment: @AndreyKomisarov The only other way is to change `min` into function object, let me add that to the answer.